# Does non-Euclidian geometries induce euclidian geometry locally?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, euclidean-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

This is essentially a soft question.

We know the world is a sphere, following spherical geometry, yet at local levels, we can observe euclidian geometry. This brings me to my question,

> Does non-Euclidian geometries induce euclidian geometry locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that I'd say non-Euclidean geometries induce Euclidean geometry locally, but I'm not a geometer. The key idea behind what you observe regarding spheres is that any manifold (like a sphere) is locally homeomorphic to Euclidean space.

Comment: I am new to non-euclidian geometries. What is the key idea behind the proof of the fact that any manifold is locally homeomorphic to euclidian space?

Comment: It's actually just a part of the definition of a manifold.

Comment: I think the question deserves more attention than this answer gives.

Comment: @Zeekless Nope, I think this answer is sufficient :-).